# Need to put for each slider image, an a link to the button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the code, I need to put a link to the button inside the table-cell for each image when it is appearing due animation.

I prefer it to be a css or html help rather than javascript, or simple native javascript will help. thanks.

```
<section id="home" class="parallax">
        <div class="slider" style="background:url('assets/images/demo/slider/flickr_01.jpg')"></div>
        <div class="slider" style="background:url('assets/images/demo/slider/flickr_02.jpg')"></div>
        <div class="slider" style="background:url('assets/images/demo/slider/flickr_03.jpg')"></div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            <a href="#about" class="scrollTo btn btn-default">CONOCE MAS</a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Please provide more code, like the javascript part handling your slideshow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### JavaScript solution

My approach is:

- give to your slides a `data-url` attribute.
- when changing the slide, get `data-url` of the current slide and assign it to `href` attribute of the link.

Voilà! I hope this will answer you:

**Snippet**

```js
var sliders = [...document.getElementsByClassName("slider")],
  link = document.querySelector("a"),
  current = 0;
  
// When link is clicked, log the href
link.addEventListener("click", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(link.href);
});
  
changeSlide();

function changeSlide() {
  sliders.forEach(slider => slider.style.display = "none");
  sliders[current].style.display = "block";
  link.href = sliders[current++].getAttribute("data-url");
  
  current %= sliders.length;
  setTimeout(changeSlide, 2000);
}
```

```css
#home {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

.slider {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

a {
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<section id="home" class="parallax">
  <div class="slider" style="background: #faa" data-url="#red"></div>
  <div class="slider" style="background: #ada" data-url="#green"></div>
  <div class="slider" style="background: #ed9" data-url="#yellow"></div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <a href="#about" class="scrollTo btn btn-default">CONOCE MAS</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap each image div class with hyperlink tag. So the each image itself became a clickable button that links to other webpage or site.

```
<a href=“#about">
  <div class="slider" style="background:url('assets/images/demo/slider/flickr_01.jpg')">
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: If you can provide more codes, it will help us to answer the question.

Comment: also, do you want to make your image clickable as a link? or you want display separate buttons below your image slider?